# How can I align the background image to an object?

Tags: 3d-view

I am creating a cartoon character over a drawing in Blender 2.76. The drawing has the grid floor at mid waist. However the bottom of the feet of the character are on the grid floor in front of the drawing. How can I move the drawing up to match the character? (I do not want to move the character down to match the drawing)

Answer (score 4):

Adjust the Y setting in the background images tab to raise or lower your background image. You can also you the X value to offset the image on the X dimension.

[image]

Comment: Using import image as plane function in the import add-on will give you more control, just another way of working with reference planes.

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. There's also Image empties. The only problem with those is that they aren't really designed for this so you have to manually rotate them to the right view and stuff, and it's also MUCH harder to get them to work for the camera view.